# Theos - Undefined Symbols For a single class in UIKit

Tags: objective-c, ios5, theos

I haven't had any problems using UIKit classes until I tried to use a UIPopoverController, now I get the linker error:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIPopoverController", referenced from:
      __objc_classrefs__DATA@0 in Tweak.xm.c4a09c77.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
```

I've made sure I have UIKit in my make file so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most certainly that you have a version of the development sysroot that doesn't yet have `UIPopoverController` (i. e. it's older than the iOS 3.2 SDK). Change to a newer version of development sysroot. The latest available is 6.1.

Comment: Okay, can I update it by copying the frameworks folders from Xcode to the relevant directory under sysroot(/var/sdk I believe?)?

Comment: @WilliamVilleneuve Yes, you can.